# How to use optimistic locking with Spring Data MongoDB?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I'm going through [Spring Data MongoDB - Reference Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.7.2.RELEASE/reference/html/) and I'm finding the examples to be a bit too simplistic.

In particular I'm trying to understand how to handle stale data in concurrent environments. For instance, imagine I have the following entity:

```
public class Person {

    private final String username;
    private final String firstname;
    private final String lastname;

    [...]

}
```

Now if I use `CrudRepository` to save/update/remove my entities, then imagine a scenario in which two threads retrieve the same entity, one of them removes it, and the other one updates its `lastname` field. If the `delete` call completes before the `save` call then my entity will be removed and then re-created, when the expected behaviour would be for the `save` operation to fail.

So far I've seen two options for getting around this issue:

1. Use `@Version` annotation. Could not find any documentation saying Spring Data supports optimistic locking in MongoDB using versioned documents. If anyone can point me to a link it'd be appreciated.
2. Use `MongoOperations.findAndModify` and fail if it returns `null`. The downside to this approach is that I can no longer implement my repository API to have "get entity" and "save updated entity" kind of semantics. e.g.:

   ```
   User user = userRepository.findByUsername("uniqueUsername");
   user.setLastName("Archer");
   userRepository.update(user);
   ```

I would have to push some of this to the repository I guess:

```
userRepository.updateLastname("uniqueUsername", "Archer");
```

But I'm a little bit worried my repository interfaces will grow uncontrollably if every type of update I want to do requires a new method.

I realise I haven't actually stated a question yet, so here it goes: what's the best-practice for designing an application using Spring Data for MongoDB?

Answer (score 15):

Using `@org.springframework.data.annotation.Version` on a property should do the trick. I've created [DATAMONGO-1275](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1275) to improve the documentation on that.

Comment: If i understand it correctly this will throw an OptimisticLockException only when updating right? Is it possible to also support delete?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.10.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#mongo-template.optimistic-locking document link

Comment: It would have been more helpful if the documentation specified the fully qualified path of the Version annotation to use, ended up here to verify that.