# Spring Boot concurrency issue for database calls

Tags: java, sql, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I am working on a Spring Boot application. The problem I am facing is related to clusters. Below is a snippet of the example code.
Suppose, I want to create an order, in which each person has a number (just an assumption). To create the order, it first gets the number from FOO table. Then saves the order in Order table. After that, the number is incremented and saved in the Foo table.

Now, if we have a cluster environment, and concurrent request are coming to createOrder() for same person then I want the Foo Table to be locked (for the read/write operation). If the person is different then lock should not be performed.

Is there any solution for that in Spring Boot regardless of database.

```
@Transactional
public void createOrder(String person){
  Long number = getNumber(person);
  //some other operations on person
  // save the order with the particular number and person
  // increment the number
  number++;
  setNumber(number, person);
}

public int getNumber(String person){
  // gets the number for the particular person from the database
}

public void setNumber(int number, String person){
  //saves the number for the particular person in the database
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This really has nothing to do with Spring Boot nor multiple servers.  This problem will exist in any environment that supports concurrent requests.

There are basically two general approaches:

## Synchronization / locking

With an auto-incrementing ID, you need a central authority to govern the ID's to prevent duplicates.  Where/how this happens is up to you.  Here are some options.  I start with what I think are the worst options, explain the pros/cons and work my way towards better options.

1. Keep the approach you have, but also add in a lock around the `createOrder` method.  Now, the JVM is the governor of the ID's.  This won't work if you have multiple servers.  Therefore, the lock ownership needs to be outside of the JVM.
2. If your servers are aware of each other through some sort of clustering library (JGroups, Hazelcast, etc.), then you can have a distributed lock where each JVM coordinates who may enter this method.  This requires your nodes to understand each other, and brings in service discovery, multicast, fault isolation, etc. into the picture.  Distributed locks are risky.  What if the node holding the lock stops responding due to a memory issue?
3. Pick an external system to manage a lock, like Redis.  Redis has a way of creating a lock and nobody else can create that same lock while somebody else holds it.  This is similar to the previous solution, but somebody has spent their time solving some of the challenges for you.
4. Use your database as the lock manager.  Guess what?  Any RDBMS that supports ACID transactions already has well-tested locking mechanisms built in.  Why is this better than #3?  Because RDBMS's are usually terrific at locking, there is usually only a single database server, so the distributed lock challenges are missing, **plus**, fault isolation is a non-issue.  If your database is down, you have bigger problems than race conditions in this one method.  You can generally count on your database being up.  Let's not get into distributed databases yet.
5. Put the ID generation itself into the database.  Every database engine I have worked with has a mechanism to auto-generate incrementing ID's when records are inserted.  For example, Oracle and PostgreSQL have sequences.  MySQL has `auto_increment`.  SQL Server has "identity" columns.  They're all the same concept.  This is better than the above approaches because it limits the locking scope.  Databases already know how to atomically handle the `id = (previous id++)` by wrapping it around a lock.  It need not put everything else in the lock.  It also cuts network communication out of the locking.  Basically, this is way simpler.  Databases know how to do it.  It just works.  It's efficient.

Notice the pattern here where I am progressively pushing the lock management down the stack and refining the locking scope.  Locks limit throughput, but prevent bad data.  The trick is to find the minimal locking scope necessary to protect your data integrity and have absolutely no more than that.

Now, if you have a distributed database (meaning, multiple database servers), this gets tricky again.  I'll let you research that subject if you're interested.

## Distributed ID generation

An alternative is to generate ID's in a purely random way so that you don't have to worry about two threads or servers generating the same ID's.  In other words, sidestep the problem.

Approaches:

1. Generate a random number.  This can get a little tricky.  Computers are surprisingly bad at randomness.
2. Generate a UUID/GUID.  This is my favorite approach.  Every language I have worked with has a simple way to generate a UUID.  A UUID is just a random number that is 128-bits, with stipulations in order to improve randomness and uniqueness.  For example, some versions of UUID include millisecond-precision timestamp, so two UUID's generated a millisecond apart cannot possibly collide (pretending clock skew doesn't exist).  Some versions of UUID's include MAC addresses.

This was a long answer with a ton of academic considerations.  My preference is to use UUID's because frankly, it's easy and avoids the concurrency problem altogether.

TL;DR

Use UUID's.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier

Comment: i will go for mongoDb saved procedure. with some script which will do the following 
 findPersonNumberAndSaveOrderAndIncrementPersonNumber() , i have to use MongoBee to save such procedure and later in  my service use this procedure in my createOrder() method. Do u think it would be a good idea?

Comment: MongoDB also has the ability to auto-generate ids.  It's a random string with the timestamp built in, very similar to UUID.  Just leave the `_id` field blank and MongoDB will fill it.  I very strongly recommend avoid rolling your own auto-incrementing ID mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation will depend on how contended is the person number, or whatever other database resource you are guarding. If you expect few conflicts during updates you most likely want to implement an optimistic locking solution. Otherwise the pessimistic locking might be better, but you probably want to benchmark either way.

A good starting point is to read [Hibernate docs, Chapter 5. Locking](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch05.html) to understand the difference in approach. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32089081/1602555) suggests that using Spring Data MongoDB you can use `@org.springframework.data.annotation.Version` annotation to get optimistic locking.

Comment: thanks for the nice answer. In my implementation, multiple nodes will for sure change the FOO table. Is there anything such as Lock the table if the person is same else don't lock.

Comment: @user2083529 locks are expensive and sometimes hard to recover, e.g. what happens when you application crashes while the table is locked? I'd recommend not to implement your own solution as a first step, instead looking for a solution specific to your database.

Comment: yes i agree with u on that, that's why i was looking for locking mechanism which looks for one particular field