# How to synchronize microservices instances running in a jetty cluster using Java Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, locking, jetty, microservices

I am developing a Java 8 Spring 5 microservice that runs on a Jetty embedded server. I intend to spawn several instances of this microservice, so there will be several Jetty servers running concurrently on different ports, one for each spawned instance.

All instances share the same database which is a MongoDB database.

From within my microservice I invoke a third party REST Web Service. I am saving the data returned by this REST WS in my database, so all instances of the cluster can take advantage of the request made by one of the instances.

However, this data expires after some time, so one instance will have to invoke the external Web Service after some time.

I do not want two or more instances of my cluster to invoke this external web service at the same time, if one instance is invoking this web service, and another one requires the data, it should wait for the first instance to retrieve the data and then use it.

This is when i find the problem, because i do not know how to lock one instance of the jetty server when another one is invoking the web service.

I have been looking into MongoDBs 4.0 Transaction feature, to try and lock a document while the service is being invoked, but without success (still :) ).

Comment: This is more a programming technique question than a coding question but I will say this... check out a system that can provide distributed locking such as Hazelcast or Apache Zookeeper.

Comment: @AndyBrown Actually i do not see it as a programming technique question since clearly the solution is heavily bounded to the technologies being used. For example, if the DB was a relational data base, then its easy to lock both processes.

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to serialize access to this external service, that is, to ensure a single request is performed at any particular moment in time.

This is that thing the databases are really good at. With a specially crafted unique index you get exactly that. You don't even need transactions for this, because you will have only one collection (table).

The solution is to use optimistic locking. I haven't used myself in Java (only in PHP) but I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32085113/how-to-use-optimistic-locking-with-spring-data-mongodb) that could help you. Long story short, you use `@org.springframework.data.annotation.Version` on a property.

You should define a new Entity that represents the remote piece of data, having a `state` property with the following possible values: `old` (the default), `fetching` and `fetched` . When a local service needs the data, it loads the Entity and check the status:

- if the status is `fetched` then it uses it;
- if the status is `old`, then it tries to change it to `fetching`; if the database rejects it because of concurrent modification then it should wait until the status becomes `fetched`; if the saving succeeds then it calls the remote service and persist the result in the Entity as a property;
- if the status is `fetching` it should wait until it becomes `fetched`.

Comment: This is almost a good solution, the only problem is that it uses busy waiting; i.e. if the server is fetching i will wait for some time and retrieve the record from the database again, and it might still be fetching. This uses unnecessary processor power, as well as database accesses.. I would need the thread that reads the record while it is being fetched to block until other thread that already has the lock updates the record with either fetched, or old.

Comment: @jsmrt what is the difference between `busy waiting` and `locking`? In this solution the instances could run on different machines and could perform other tasks instead of waiting. If you need only threads  then maybe a simple `synchronized method` would suffice. I propose this solution because you used the term "cluster" which implies distributed systems

Comment: @ Constantin Galbenu what i mean is, how would you implement this part of the algorithm: " if the database rejects it because of concurrent modification then it should wait until the status becomes fetched ", if it is by doing a while(true) loop with a sleep in the middle and asking the database repeatedly whether the status has changed, that is busy waiting, and its ugly. I like the idea but i do not know how to make the database raise an event when the status value changes so the thread can wake up instead of having to poll the status of the record.

Comment: @jsmrt you can tail the `oplog` https://github.com/JaiHirsch/mongo-tail